# Set style for connector and endpoints on hover

Tags: jsplumb

I'm trying to create a css style for all connections and endpoints which are connected to a specific element. I have managed to color all source/targets but I'm not managing to color the connections (lines)

Here is my current code...

```
var endpoints = jsPlumb.getEndpoints(this);

for (var i = 0; i < endpoints.length; i++) {
if (endpoints[i].connections[0] != null) {
    $(endpoints[i].connections[0].target).addClass('red_color');
    $(endpoints[i].connections[0].source).addClass('red_color');
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connection` class also has an `addClass` method. So you could call

```
endpoints[i].connections[0].addClass('red_color')
```

and then, as discussed at https://docs.jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/lib/styling-via-css#css-for-svg-elements, you can target the connector path like this:

```
svg.red_color path {
  stroke:red;
  stroke-width:3;
}
```